# Visual Studio 2015: How to disable "How do I..." feature

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I am using `Visual Studio Community 2015`. Whenever I use intellisense menu, the `"How do I.."` option always be selected by default on the top and that is quite annoying me.

[image]

So could I disable that feature?

Comment: I don't see it in my Visual Studio. Do you have a screenshot illustrating the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore it. Just because I have installed the [Developer Assisstant Extensions](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a1166718-a2d9-4a48-a5fd-504ff4ad1b65) for Visual Studio 2015.